# Multiple(10-15) Columns Referring back to same Table

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-server-2008-r2, query-performance

I have a situation where I have almost 10 to 15 Columns in a table Referencing back to one table I know how to JOIN Multiple Times with Aliases to retrieve values But in this case when I have 10 Column , Doing 10 joins seems like an OVER KILL, Can someone advise a Simpler Performance Efficient Method for this.

**Table_One**

```
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Id | Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | Column5 | Column6 | Column7 | Column8 |
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  1 | Y       | N       | N       | Y       | R       | NA      | N       | NA      |
|  2 | N       | R       | NA      | N       | N       | Y       | Y       | R       |
|  3 | Y       | R       | NA      | NA      | R       | NA      | NA      | Y       |
|  4 | N       | N       | R       | Y       | Y       | R       | R       | Y       |
|  5 | R       | Y       | Y       | R       | Y       | N       | Y       | R       |
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

**Table_Two**

```
+----+----------------+---------+
| ID |    ColumnA     | Deleted |
+----+----------------+---------+
| N  | NO             |       0 |
| NA | NOT APPLICABLE |       0 |
| R  | REFUSED        |       0 |
| Y  | YES            |       0 |
+----+----------------+---------+
```

**What I have tried so Far**

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE
(
    PrimaryKey INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    CaseDate DATETIME,
    ClientID INT,
    Column1 CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    Column2 CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    Column3 CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    Column4 NUMERIC(28,2) NOT NULL,
    Column5 NUMERIC(28,2) NOT NULL,
    Column6 NUMERIC(28,2) NOT NULL,
    Column7 NUMERIC(28,2) NOT NULL,
    Column8 NUMERIC(28,2) NOT NULL
)
INSERT  @Table1 
VALUES ('2013-12-01 09:44:11.854',1,'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 26, 23, 22, 24, 19),
       ('2013-12-07 06:44:23.102',1,'Y', 'R', 'NA',22, 24,27, 27,26),
       ('2013-12-09 07:44:07.685',2,'Y', 'Y', 'NA',23, 25, 28, 28, 24),
       ('2013-12-11 09:44:02.545',2,'N', 'N', 'R',24, 30,28, 39,27),
       ('2013-12-11 06:41:19.465',2,'R', 'Y', 'Y',27, 27,26, 27, 24)
DECLARE @Table2 TABLE
(
    ID CHAR(2) PRIMARY KEY,
    ColumnA VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Deleted BIT 
)
INSERT @Table2  
VALUES ('Y', 'YES'            , 0),
       ('N', 'NO'             , 0),
       ('R', 'REFUSED'        , 0),
       ('NA', 'NOT APPLICABLE', 0)


SELECT * 
FROM @Table1 
WHERE Column1 IN ('N', 'R')
OR Column2 IN ('N', 'R')
OR Column3 IN ('N', 'R')

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ClientID ORDER BY [CaseDate] DESC)
    FROM (SELECT * 
            FROM @Table1 
            WHERE Column1 IN ('N', 'R')
            OR Column2 IN ('N', 'R')
            OR Column3 IN ('N', 'R')) A
)
SELECT  X.ClientID,
        CAST(X.[CaseDate] AS DATE) [CaseDate],
        X.Column1,
        X.Column4,
        ISNULL(X.Column4,0) - ISNULL(Y.Column4,0) C4_Change,
        X.Column2,
        X.Column5,
        ISNULL(X.Column5,0) - ISNULL(Y.Column5,0) C5_Change,
        X.Column3,
        X.Column6,
        ISNULL(X.Column6,0) - ISNULL(Y.Column6,0) C6_Change
FROM CTE X
LEFT JOIN CTE Y
    ON X.RN = Y.RN - 1
ORDER BY X.[CaseDate] DESC
```

**Result Set**

```
ClientID    CaseDate  Column1   Column4 C4_Change  Column2  Column5 C5_Change Column3   Column6 C6_Change
2         2013-12-11    N        24.00  -3.00         N     30.00   3.00          R     28.00   2.00
2         2013-12-11    R        27.00  27.00         Y     27.00   27.00         Y     26.00   26.00
1         2013-12-07    Y        22.00  -5.00         R     24.00   -3.00         NA    27.00   1.00
```

Comment: I don't know how you're going to get a less complex query than that, and how doing so would make whatever you're doing outside of the scope of this question less complex. How can someone judge "a bit simpler"? How do we know what makes the "extremely difficult" stuff you haven't shown us extremely difficult, and whether our solution helps there? I will recommend that you don't just throw join hints like `MERGE` and `HASH` unless you absolutely know what you're doing... I suggest removing it from this question to avoid further "why are you doing that?" questions.

Comment: Based on your sample data what do you want the final result to look like?  You have obviously provided a simplistic version but then you say that your existing `pivot`/`unpivot` won't work because of other calculations and string concatenations, do you expect us to guess exactly what you need the query to do?

Comment: @AaronBertrand the reason I used this query is because when I join this table_one to Table_Two 8 times using Aliases to get the values in all the 8 columns, The query Takes over 3 mins to run when I use this query PIVOT/UNPIVOT query it executed just under a minute.

Comment: I'm not sure how that addresses anything I previously said.

Comment: @bluefeet all I am asking for is can I get the values of all these 8 columns without joining 8 times to the table_Two ??

Comment: The answer is yes, you can use unpivot/pivot, but then you say it is not simple enough and the query we're looking at is actually a lot more complex in real life. Stand in our shoes for a moment and try to visualize how we could possibly solve this problem for you.

Comment: @AaronBertrand this is just an example some of my tables has 10-15 these Yes/no Columns, I want to be able to retrieve values from all these columns with out using multiple joins.

Comment: Are you reading anything I'm writing?

Comment: @MuhammedAli Since you need to join on a de-normalized table and you don't want to join 8+ times you have your answer = `unpivot`.  If your problem is actually more complex than what you described above, then you should include all relevant details to properly answer your question.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I am sorry guys if I have not been able to describe the whole situation in detail. When I am retrieving these results , I am also retrieving some other 10 columns as well , retrieving these 10-15 columns plus another 10 Columns, using PIVOT/UNPIVOT query on 25-30 Columns becomes really difficult and a but messy code and debugging it when something goes wrong becomes even more difficult as I am no expert in PIVOT queries, All I am looking for it a query without any pivots and multiple joins. if it is possible please

Comment: Can you simplify your case to just 2 references instead of 10-15 and **actually show us precisely** (in your question) what you are doing, so that we can apprehend the issue? At this point an example is much more valuable than a verbal description.

Comment: How many rows do you have in your tables?

Comment: @MikaelEriksson in Table_One 550K plus

Comment: And table2? I was thinking that if you have few rows in table2 you could build a dynamic thing that uses a case statement in the field list. It will not be less complicated but could be a lot faster. With the data in the Q the case would look like 8 of these. `case T1.Column1 when 'Y' then 'YES' when 'N' then 'NO' when 'R' then 'REFUSED' when 'NA' then 'NOT APPLICABLE' end`

Comment: @MikaelEriksson there are only 4 rows in this Table_B but recently We have added another row and my bad I had to change all these Case statements in almost 30 different reports and in each report has like 10-15 Columns where I have had used case statement, I dont want to do this ever again thats why I am looking for another solution, Thanks for your advice though :)

Comment: @AaronBertrand I have edited my question with a bit more descriptive scenario, Now the result set is somewhat I would have, Any clients who has Said `No` or `Refused` I am getting their last 3 readings and their differences from prior values. now in this result set I would like to show values from Table_B for the columns Column1, Column2 and Column3. Please have a look and advise thank you.

Comment: @bluefeet I have edited my question with a bit more descriptive scenario, Now the result set is somewhat I would have, Any clients who has Said `No` or `Refused` I am getting their last 3 readings and their differences from prior values. now in this result set I would like to show values from Table_B for the columns Column1, Column2 and Column3. Please have a look and advise thank you

Comment: I tried your query with 500K rows and I don't see what you see. Pivot with merge hint 17 seconds, hash hint 11 seconds, no hint 9 seconds and 8 joins took 2 seconds. (SQL Server 2012 on a really old laptop with one dual core processor). All the pivot versions spilled to tempdb and the join version did not.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson please have a look in my edited question I have added more details, maybe this will help you to put me in the right direction.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson Did you create any indexes on the table ???

Comment: Nope, I used this setup. http://pastebin.com/QSy9mvxf